# Normal/Applicative Order Reduction

Tags: haskell

In terms of evaluating function applications does Haskell only support normal order reduction or does it also support applicative order reduction? Am I correct in thinking that normal order is what gives Haskell its laziness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GHC runtime does not use a term reduction strategy, since that would be very inefficient. Indeed, GHC is a proper compiler, targeting the STG-machine as an abstract machine for its runtime.

Still, it achieves the same semantics of normal order reduction -- i.e. non-strict semantics.

One can still force some arguments to be evaluated, as in applicative order reduction as follows:

```
foo x y = x `seq` actualFoo x y
```

Above, `x` is evaluated immediately, while `y` is not.

Other common equivalent patterns:

```
foo x y | seq x False = undefined
foo x y = actualFoo x y

-- or, with a GHC extension

foo !x y = actualFoo x y
```